# Setting a variable equal to a variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm working on a problem even my colleagues say is impossible. There is XML already in our database and I want to be able to take single attributes from the XML and set them equal to variables to work with. This is my code so far (that doesn't work).

```
    declare @MyText varchar(10)

    declare @MyXML XML
    set @MyXML = '
    <ns0:TestXML xmlns:ns0="http://test.com">
    <TestValue>11</TestValue>
    </ns0:TestXML>'


   set @MyText = 
   (
       ;with XMLNAMESPACES ('http://test.com' as ns0)
       set @MyText = 
       (
           select 
               a.bo.value('(/ns0:TestXML2[1]/TestXML3)[1]','INT') as [Number]
           from @MyXML.nodes('ns0:TestXML') a(bo)
       )
   )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you. Also if my logic is completely off about how SQL works with XML, please don't hesitate to educate me.

Comment: is the xml typed in the db?

Answer (score 0):

How's this, it returns `11` from the provided `XML` which is what you want I assume:

```
declare @MyText varchar(10)

declare @MyXML XML
set @MyXML = '
<ns0:TestXML xmlns:ns0="http://test.com">
<TestValue>11</TestValue>
</ns0:TestXML>'

;with XMLNAMESPACES ('http://test.com' as ns0)
    select @MyText =
        a.bo.value('(/ns0:TestXML)[1]','INT') 
    from @MyXML.nodes('ns0:TestXML') a(bo)

select @MyText as [TheImpossibleValue]
```